# Include/inherit single django form into multiple templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django form that i would like to be replicated/included among many templates of my django website similarly to the way you use the `{% include %}`, is there a good way to do this without having to repeat my code in all the views of the templates that require the form?

here is my **forms.py**

```
class ServiceForm(forms.Form):
           SERVICE = (

            ('service 1','service 1'),

            ('service 2','service 2'),

            ('service 3','service 3'),

            ('service 4', 'service 4')

        )
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    phone = forms.IntegerField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    service = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=SERVICE)
    message = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))`
```

Comment: We are using ```Form``` for data validation and rendering purposes. You are talking about ```HTML``` you mean rendering this case (IMHO). Use ```context processors```.

Comment: ```context processor``` is just a function, which takes ```WSGIRequest``` object and return ```dict```. You should pass your ```Form``` object in this dict, and this will be visible for every template context.

Comment: "having to repeat my code in all the views", which code would you repeat? If you're using class-based views, you never need to repeat code, just write a mixin class that you can add to your views.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks the mixin class worked for me perfectly.